# Appium: Super slow Robot Framework automated tests (Xiaomi)

Tags: android, performance, appium, robotframework

I have a **simple test app** (react-native) with a few buttons, that invoke a toast message. I wrote simple test cases in **Robot Framework** to click on the individual buttons and then wait for the toast to show up.

Everything was running well until last week. The tests became **unusably slow** (every interaction takes too much time). Normally a tap took a **second or two**, now it can take **up to minute**. Only the start initial connection and start of the application is normal.

I am running the tests on a local machine (Mac) with a real device (Xiaomi).

### Setup:

- **Appium: 1.22.2**
- Robot Framework 4.1.3 (Python 3.9.10 on darwin)
- MacOS 12.2.1
- Phone: Xiaomi Redmi Note 7

  - Android: 10
  - MIUI: 12.5.3

---

When I run the tests on a **different device** (Samsung), it **works just fine**. (using that other device isn't a solution, the device isn't mine)

---

Here is my `Suite Setup`:

```python
***Keywords***
Start App
    &{deviceConfig}=  Create Dictionary
    Set To Dictionary  ${deviceConfig}  platformName=android
    Set To Dictionary  ${deviceConfig}  platformVersion=10
    Set To Dictionary  ${deviceConfig}  udid=c15dded3
    Set To Dictionary  ${deviceConfig}  appPackage=com.toastexamplestest
    Set To Dictionary  ${deviceConfig}  appActivity=.MainActivity
    Set To Dictionary  ${deviceConfig}  automationName=uiautomator2

    Open Application  http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub  &{deviceConfig}
```

Here is one of the test cases:

```python
React native root toast
    Tap  ${btn_root_toast}
    Wait For Error  //android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, '${toast_text_root_toast}' )]

    Sleep  5s

    Tap  ${btn_root_toast}
    Wait For Error  //android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, '${toast_text_root_toast}' )]
```

(`Wait For Error` is just a wrapper for `Wait Until Page Contains Element`)

**Test Setup** is just `Launch Application`
and **Test Teardown** is just `Quit Application`

### Appium Logs:

```code
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

...

[BaseDriver] W3C capabilities and MJSONWP desired capabilities were provided
[BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
[BaseDriver]     "platformName": "android",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:platformVersion": "10",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:udid": "c15dded3",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:appPackage": "com.toastexamplestest",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:appActivity": ".MainActivity",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:automationName": "uiautomator2"
[BaseDriver]   },
[BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
[BaseDriver]     {}
[BaseDriver]   ]
[BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde
[UiAutomator2] Starting 'com.toastexamplestest' directly on the device
[ADB] Using 'adb' from '/Users/marekd/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb'

...

[ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"c15dded3","state":"device"}]
[AndroidDriver] Using device: c15dded3

...

[WD Proxy] socket hang up
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] socket hang up
[Instrumentation] io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test.AppiumUiAutomator2Server:
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] socket hang up
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"None","value":{"message":"UiAutomator2 Server is ready to accept commands","ready":true}}
[UiAutomator2] The initialization of the instrumentation process took 3080ms

...

[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/appium/app/launch 200 963 ms - 14
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/elements
[HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.widget.Button[1]"}
[W3C (d97552ab)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: ["xpath","//android.widget.Button[1]","d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde"]
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, css selector, -android uiautomator
[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[WD Proxy] Matched '/elements' to command name 'findElements'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /elements] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a/elements] with body: {"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.Button[1]","context":"","multiple":true}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a","value":[{"ELEMENT":"00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011","element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011"}]}
[W3C (d97552ab)] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: [{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011","ELEMENT":"00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011"}]
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/elements 200 10355 ms - 139
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/touch/perform
[HTTP] {"actions":[{"action":"tap","options":{"element":"00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011","count":1}}]}
[W3C (d97552ab)] Calling AppiumDriver.performTouch() with args: [[{"action":"tap","options":{"element":"00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011","count":1}}],"d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde"]
[UiAutomator2] calling get location: 00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011
[WD Proxy] Matched '/element/00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011/location' to command name 'getLocation'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /element/00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011/location] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a/element/00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011/location] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a","value":{"x":11,"y":832}}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/element/00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011/size' to command name 'getSize'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /element/00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011/size] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a/element/00000000-0000-0049-ffff-ffff00000011/size] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a","value":{"height":97,"width":1058}}
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /appium/tap] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a/appium/tap] with body: {"x":540,"y":880.5,"undefined":null}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a","value":null}
[W3C (d97552ab)] Responding to client with driver.performTouch() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/touch/perform 200 50417 ms - 14
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/elements
[HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'This is a message' )]"}
[W3C (d97552ab)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: ["xpath","//android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'This is a message' )]","d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde"]
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, css selector, -android uiautomator
[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[WD Proxy] Matched '/elements' to command name 'findElements'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /elements] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a/elements] with body: {"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'This is a message' )]","context":"","multiple":true}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a","value":[]}
[W3C (d97552ab)] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: []
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/elements 200 10093 ms - 12
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/elements
[HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'This is a message' )]"}
[W3C (d97552ab)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: ["xpath","//android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'This is a message' )]","d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde"]
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, css selector, -android uiautomator
[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[WD Proxy] Matched '/elements' to command name 'findElements'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /elements] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a/elements] with body: {"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'This is a message' )]","context":"","multiple":true}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a","value":[]}
[W3C (d97552ab)] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: []
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/elements 200 10083 ms - 12
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/source
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (d97552ab)] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[WD Proxy] Matched '/wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/source' to command name 'getPageSource'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/source] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a/source] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a","value":"\r\n\r\n  \r\n    \r\n      
[WD Proxy] Replacing sessionId cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a with d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/source 200 10186 ms - 10712
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/screenshot
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (d97552ab)] Calling AppiumDriver.getScreenshot() with args: ["d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde"]
[WD Proxy] Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/cae5d25f-d594-4ec4-90de-bbc34238a12a/screenshot] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"cae5d25f-d594-4ec4...
[W3C (d97552ab)] Responding to client with driver.getScreenshot() result: "iVBORw0K...
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/screenshot 200 608 ms - 140626
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/appium/app/close
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (d97552ab)] Calling AppiumDriver.closeApp() with args: ["d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde"]
[ADB] Running '/Users/marekd/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s c15dded3 shell am force-stop com.toastexamplestest'
[W3C (d97552ab)] Responding to client with driver.closeApp() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/d97552ab-31db-42f1-b98d-d23549f2efde/appium/app/close 200 86 ms - 14
```

The log isn't complete, couldn't fit it all here.